# How to do session based filtering servlet authentication

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

I am currently using filter to authenticate credentials given in the REST and servlet calls done in the servlet.

Everytime when a request made it fetches the credentials from the database which is expensive operation everytime.

Is there any way to authenticate based on session so that need not go everytime to retrieve details from db.

Thanks.

Comment: After doing the DB lookup once add some token to a static Map and add that token to the users session

Comment: Instead of a static Map use some caching implementation for replication and lifetime managememt

Comment: You can use something like redis for storing info or program a simple custom class, just remember to expire tokens with some logic if you code it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be Token based mechanism. Once the user logged in he's given a token and resending API calls with that token from the client will give the client to access the API.

Refer this : [Implementing authentication with tokens](https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can create token when user getting first time successfully login and save that token in caching  server and set in cookies also whenever request comes from client check from caching server instead of Data base.Set token expire time as per session expire time.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options you have

1. Keep the session token in memory. Each app server has a way to replicate in-memory session cache. Indeed it requires some cache management around.

Most of the solutions I've seen and done used this option.

2. You can use a self-containing token (such as JWT) the filter should be able to validate without accessing DB every time. Then you will need a token service to exchange the client credentials for the token.

If your clients use directly their credentials (basic authentication), you may consider some way to use tokens which are more secure to cache (OAuth 2.0)

When someone has improvent or disagreement, feel free to comment